# horizontally center element without fractional offset?

Tags: html, css

`margin: 0 auto` will horizontally center an element. However, depending on the parent and child size, sometimes `getBoundingClientRect` returns a fractional left value (as does jQuery offset).  These fractions cause problems elsewhere in javascript code, so I would like to remove them (instead of compensate for them).

Is there a way to use css to horizontally center with an integer offset?  Or should I just use javascript?

---

There are lots of horizontal alignment questions, but none which seem to address this issue of subpixel perplexities.

```js
var br = document.getElementById("kid").getBoundingClientRect();

document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "left: " + br.left;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#pop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 401px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
#kid {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="pop">
  <div id="kid"></div>
  <div id="info">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u please show your code?

Comment: getBoundingClientRect should return an integer, there is not such thing as a fractional pixel. Do you use css transform ?

Comment: I do not know of a method of "centering" a div without the chance of fractional pixels getting involved... and since different browsers have different subpixel rendering methods, I would certainly compensate for that with javascript.

Comment: example added to the op

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect` so it returns rounded numbers.

This will also affect jQuery methods that rely on it, such as `offset()`, `width()`, and `height()`:

```
Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect= function() {
  var parent= this.parentNode instanceof HTMLElement ? this.parentNode : null,
      left  = Math.round(this.offsetLeft + (parent && parent.getBoundingClientRect().left)),
      top   = Math.round(this.offsetTop  + (parent && parent.getBoundingClientRect().top)),
      width = Math.round(this.offsetWidth),
      height= Math.round(this.offsetHeight);

  return {
    left:    left,
    top:     top,
    right:   left+width,
    bottom:  top+height,
    width:   width,
    height:  height
  }
} //getBoundingClientRect
```

In [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2ymdh1z/), you'll see the element's fractional dimensions using JavaScript and jQuery.  `getBoundingClientRect` is then redefined.

Click the button, and you'll see rounded dimensions based on the updated method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you absolutely can use integers! However, you'll have location issues unless you use a system that is measured in integers as it's smallest unit of measurement.  Are there such units? Yes! They are called pixels, and are square units that can be represented with positive whole numbers (i.e. integers).  Simply make sure that you're referencing pixels in your CSS and NOT percentages or number of column spans and you'll have exactly what you're after...